# How to set http body request efficiently?

Tags: ios, nsdictionary, parameter-passing, key-value, http-request

in my app, I'm currently sending http requests from each viewcontroller. However, currently I'm implementing one class, that is supposed to have method for sending requests.

My requests vary in number of parameters. For example, to get list of things for tableview I need to put category, subcategory, filter and 5 more parameters into request.

This is what my request looks like now:

```
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]init];
         [request setValue:verifString forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"]; 
         [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://myweb.com/api/things/list"]];
         [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
         [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

         NSMutableString *bodyparams = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"sort=popularity"];
         [bodyparams appendFormat:@"&filter=%@",active];
         [bodyparams appendFormat:@"&category=%@",useful];
         NSData *myRequestData = [NSData dataWithBytes:[bodyparams UTF8String] length:[bodyparams length]];
[request setHTTPBody:myRequestData]
```

My first idea was to create method, that accepts all of these parameters, and those, which are not needed would be nil, then I would test which are nil and those which are not nil would be appended to parameter string (ms).

This is however pretty inefficient. 
Later on I was thinking about passing some dictionary with stored values for a parameter. Something like array list with nameValuePair that's used in android's java.

I'm not sure, how would I get keys and objects from my dictionary

```
    -(NSDictionary *)sendRequest:(NSString *)funcName paramList:(NSDictionary *)params 
{
  // now I need to add parameters from NSDict params somehow
  // ?? confused here :)   
}
```

Comment: Have a look at [AFNetworking](http://afnetworking.com), they have a `AFHTTPClient` which would make these kind of calls very easy.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could construct your params string from a dictionary with something like this:

```
/* Suppose that we got a dictionary with 
   param/value pairs */
NSDictionary *params = @{
    @"sort":@"something",
    @"filter":@"aFilter",
    @"category":@"aCategory"
};

/* We iterate the dictionary now
   and append each pair to an array
   formatted like <KEY>=<VALUE> */      
NSMutableArray *pairs = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0];
for (NSString *key in params) {
    [pairs addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@=%@", key, params[key]]];
}
/* We finally join the pairs of our array
   using the '&' */
NSString *requestParams = [pairs componentsJoinedByString:@"&"];
```

If you log the `requestParams` string you will get:

> filter=aFilter&category=aCategory&sort=something

PS I totally agree with @rckoenes that `AFNetworking` is the best solution for this kind of operations.

Comment: Hmm, I like your solution and I'm afraid that using things like AFNetworking may cause rejecting my app. (Thats mainly because I'm not sure if they aren't using things that are "against" apple rules)

Comment: I'm glad that helped you. Regarding `AFNetworking`, there's no way Apple could reject your app (there must be thousands of apps in the store using it right now).

Comment: Ok I'll give it a shot then :) Thanks, and also thank to you rckoenes!